# Adding a margin to a single list item in a horizontal list

Tags: css, list

Is it possible to add a margin to the top of a **certain item** in a horizontal unordered list?

I've made a cloud-themed navigation bar, but I don't want all the clouds to be all in one straight line, so I'm trying to make it so they aren't all in one line.

None of these answers have worked for me, it doesn't change the list items at all, so I've added some of the code here:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="clouds">
    <ul>
        <li id="home"><a href="#"><img src="buttons/home.png"></a></li>
        <li id="info"><a href="#"><img src="buttons/Info.png"></a></li>
        <li id="designs"><a href="#"><img src="buttons/Designs.png"></a></li>
        <li id="contact"><a href="#"><img src="buttons/Contact.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0, rgb(94,132,19)),
        color-stop(0.6, rgb(124,180,34)),
        color-stop(0.6, rgb(252,253,255)),
        color-stop(1, rgb(117,178,209))
    );
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
        center bottom,
        rgb(94,132,19) 0%,
        rgb(124,180,34) 60%,
        rgb(252,253,255) 60%,
        rgb(117,178,209) 100%
    );
    min-height: 500px;    
    text-align: center;
    background-position: absolute;
}
#sun{
    height: 72px;
    width: 72px;
    float: right;
    background-image: url('sun.png');
}

/*---NAVIGATION---*/
#home img:hover{
    background-image: url('buttons/home.png');
}
#info img:hover{
    background-image: url('buttons/info.png');
}
#designs img:hover{
    background-image: url('buttons/designs.png');
}
#contact img:hover{
    background-image: url('buttons/contact.png');
}
#clouds ul, li{
    display: inline;
    margin: 40px;
}
#clouds ul{
    display: inline;
}
/*---NAVIGATION END---*/

#wrap h1{
    margin-top: 175px;
    font-family: code bold;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #000;
}
#wrap{
    font-family: code bold;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #000;
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#text{
    font-family: kartika;
    font-size: 22;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 3em;
    -moz-column-rule: 1px dashed fff;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 3em;
    -webkit-column-rule: 1px dashed fff;
}
```

I've decided to add the whole of my stylesheet because there might be an error in there somewhere that might be causing the list item margin to not work, although I can't seem to find any problems.

Thanks for the answers and comments so far.

**It seems changing the margin of a single item only works if the list has float: left to it, it is possible to center the list instead of floating it to the left to make it work?**

Comment: what about adding margin to the contained <li> element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have two solutions for you: http://jsfiddle.net/8avbq/5/

1. You can use the `:nth-child()` selector from CSS3. You put the number of the `li` you want to target in the brackets (This method will not support IE8 and below though):

   ```
   ul li:nth-child(2){
        margin-top:15px;
        background: red;
   }
   ```
2. Set a class on the `li`:

   **HTML:**

   ```
   <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li class="extra">4</li>
      <li>5</li>
   </ul>
   ```

   **CSS:**

   ```
   ul li.extra{
       margin-top:15px;
   }
   ```

**EDIT :** Based on new question requirements. This should do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/A8mAY/7/

Comment: @henry-95: Can you please update this http://jsfiddle.net/A8mAY/ with absolute links to your images. That way I can see how the site should actually look and be able to modify it.

Comment: On a side note- The clouds make a circle in my viewport in that fiddle. :)

Comment: Yeah I needed help with that also, they go in a line when the window is bigger, I need all the clouds to **always** be horizontal, even if the window is small :)

Comment: For that, you'll need a set with on their container, so you'll want something like `#clouds { min-width: 500px; }` (flexible width beyond 500px) or `#clouds { width: 500px; }` (fixed width of 500px, regardless of viewport size). The 500px is, of course, an arbitrary number and should be whatever is big enough to hold all your clouds. I think it looks kind of cool as a circle, though. :)

Comment: Yeah thanks that fixed it, I had to put it in the body{} though.
And do you know how to fix the main problem with the clouds?

Comment: I just took a quick look at it, looks great :D really appreciate it, thanks!!

Comment: @henry-95: Glad it works for you. There were lots of changes: centred wrapper, centred clouds, no `img` tags, uses `background` instead, `float:left` instead of `display:inline` and `margin-top` is working nicely.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
#clouds ul, li{
    display: inline;
}
```

to:

```
#clouds ul, li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

That should allow you to use the top and bottom margins/padding the way you're trying to. (If you run into issues with Internet Explorer with inline-block, then try shifting the display and margins to the `<a>` tags inside your list items (`#clouds ul li a`), as old versions of IE should cooperate with elements that default to inline.

Also, is `#clouds ul, li` supposed to have the comma in it? If so, then you can remove the `#clouds ul` that follows it. As you have it, though, it will turn all your list items inline and give it the margin you have.

Comment: Changing your `li` to `inline-block` does allow it to respect top and bottom margin and padding, but depending on how the elements around it are positions/sized, it might not appear to do anything. You can use also your favorite browser's developer tools (Firefox requires an extra download - Firebug) to highlight where the margin or padding is actually going and see what's going on.

Comment: Yeah I'll have a look at it, I've put what I've done so far on JSFiddle, you can have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/A8mAY/3/

Comment: Well, one issue with your fiddle code is that you're using `class=home` in your markup, but then using `#home` (ID) in your CSS. You'll want to make sure your HTML and CSS match up. In this case, using IDs should be fine, especially if the code for each of them will be slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li>item 1</li>
   <li>item 2</li>
   <li class="certain_item">item 3</li>
   <li>item 4</li>
   <li>item 5</li>
   <li>item 6</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li
{
    float:left;
}

ul li.certain_item
{
    margin-top:15px;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aH9ra/5/

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for, I meant a horizontal list, sorry for the confusion :P

Comment: @Henry-95 I'm just demonstrating how you can apply margins to individual `li` items. You can style the rest of the list however you like :)

Comment: Ah yeah I know, but I need to change the margin of an item in a horizontal list, not a vertical list

Comment: Please see changes to my answer

Comment: I've noticed that you've put a float: left in the li style, is it possible to remove the float: left and keep the margin? I need my navigation bar to be centred

Answer (score 0):

if you have a static # of navigation items you could use `nth-child` to style them

so with this html:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Nav Item 1</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

use this css styling:

```
#nav :nth-child(1) { margin: 8px; }
#nav :nth-child(2) { margin: 5px; }
#nav :nth-child(3) { margin: 3px; }
#nav :nth-child(4) { margin: 12px; }
#nav :nth-child(5) { margin: 6px; }
```

*note:* browser support for `nth-child` is somewhat limited ( IE9+, Safari 3.1+, FF 3.5+, Chrome )