# Having trouble with making horizontal buttons

Tags: css, button, navigation, row

How do I fix this navigation bar?
I tried making it on my own but I just can't get everything to work.

[image]

This is the button in all three states:

[image]

The red background is `#490000` and it should be a separate div.

The text on top of the buttons is a custom font but that doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've thrown together a [working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/echopony/JvENG/) you could study. Can you elaborate on where you had issues so I can explain the solution?

Comment: Thank you so much! So sorry that I can't vote up yet...
The problem I had was that I couldn't get the button image to show completely. It got cut no matter what dimensions I put in CSS...

Comment: Ahhh, your issue was not setting your anchor to `display: block`, most likely. If you look at my example, try this setting on section a { - - `display: inline` rather than block. edit: The reason for this is that anchors are by default treated as inline elements in most browsers. By setting them to display as block elements, they behave more like a div for example.

Comment: You're awesome, thanks!
I couldn't figure out what was wrong and you're right, it was the inline-block thing...
I'll certainly have more questions as I'm just learning CSS by creating my own site...
Cheers!

Comment: One more question: is it possible to target just one item from the list so that you can control right padding only for for example second button so you get this:
http://i39.tinypic.com/b7josi.jpg

Comment: Absolutely. If there will only be 4 items, try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/echopony/JvENG/1/). I've simply given each list item an id, then given the outer list items' id's an extra margin on their insides. For example: `#home {margin-right: 30px;}`.

Comment: Also, where I've set the li's to use `display: inline-block`, you could replace that line with `float: left;`. Floats have very unique and specific behaviour in css, so it's good to experiment with them. Also, `display: inline-block` isn't fully supported by internet explorer. Definitely play around with it!

Comment: That's because info-bar isn't an html element. section is a new html5 element (Hopefully, anyway - It's still in drafting phase). What I would suggest, if you want to go cutting edge, is to use the nav (`<nav></nav>`) tag... That seems more semantic here. Otherwise, the reason info-bar failed is because in the css, section was referenced for a few rules. If it doesn't exist, neither do your styles. Try using a nav tag and switching the occurrences of section to nav in the css; ie `section a:hover` would become `nav a:hover`.

Comment: Glad to help. Teaching is the best form of learning. You can mark this answer as correct if you'd like to - It brings up your accept rating so people are more willing to help you out, and gives me 15 points! Haha.

Comment: One more annoying question. :)
You showed how to target specific list item and change its margin value; I guess I can only change margin-left and right and can't change the margin-top or margin-bottom because the list is inline. Is that correct?

Also, what else can I use insted of section and nav tags?
I tried regular div but I can't get the code to work. :/

Comment: Technically, as long as you replace instances of nav in the html and css with any other block element, such as div, it *should* work. Want to show me your css and html on pastebin.com or something? Otherwise, margin-top or margin-bottom on the list items will definitely work.

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/MUpmD/1/
Try changing the margin-top for #money and you'll see that all of the items shift with that change...
Please replace <section> with a div tag as it doesn't work for me...

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996802/adding-a-margin-to-a-single-list-item-in-a-horizontal-list) a thread with a solution to my question about changing top margin of a single list item.